# Google Chart error : Data column cannot be of type string

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Im using this code to generate chart. I've to push data into array in a function. Then I'll pass it to draw function. But when I do that I get this error `Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string`.
Any idea what is the issue?

```
function setData(records) {
$("#result").show();

var chartData = [];

    chartData.push(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']);

    // A SIMPLE FOR EACH LOOP STARTS
    chartData.push([
        X,Y,P,Q
    ]);
    //FOR EACH ENDS
drawVisualization(chartData);
}

google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });

function drawVisualization(chartData) {

var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    chartData
]);

var options = {
    title: 'Monthly Coffee Production by Country',
    vAxis: { title: 'Measure' },
    hAxis: { title: Row },
    seriesType: 'bars',
    series: { 5: { type: 'line' } }
};

var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the [data format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart#data-format) for a ComboChart only allows string values in the first column (x-axis)
unless it is for a special [role](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles), such as tooltip or annotation

so this must mean the data being fed to the array contains string values,
after the first column

without a sample of the data, it's hard to say for sure
but, for whatever columns should be numeric,
use `parseFloat` or `parseInt`, depending on the type of numbers in your data

if all columns should be numeric,
try something like the following snippet when loading...

```
var chartData = [];

chartData.push(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']);

chartData.push([
    parseFloat(X),
    parseFloat(Y),
    parseFloat(P),
    parseFloat(Q)
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a race condition where the chart was trying to render before I had received my data. I'm using Angular so I put an *ngIf around the chart contingent on displaying only if the flag stated the data was ready.

Another solution that worked for me was to initialize my data object (here the chartData array) with a single value rather than just an empty array, then when the data is ready clear the data object to an empty array again and add the data.